# What happens when bending laser light in a liquid stream smaller than its wavelenght?

Tags: laser, laser-cavity

When you point a laser into a water stream it bends with the waterstream and exits at the end. It bounces constantly from the "virtual wall" till it reaches the end of the stream. Now if the waterstream gets ever smaller and smaller and smaller till it is smaller in size than the wavelenght of the laser diode itself, what would happen?

(sample: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifbCsha7Syc)

Would it just heat the water at the smallest possible focal point of the laser (lets say 600nm)? OR Come quantum mechanics into play and parts/all light still travels to the end? OR Will it just be blocked mid stream and bounce back in reverse? OR something that i might not have thinked about?

All this ignoring the tension of Water (theoretical question therefore).

Comment: Google "single mode fiber". There is a minimum diameter at which even a solid dielectric waveguide can guide the beam. With a liquid you have the additional challenge of keeping the dimensions stable in a material without a definite shape.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will research that...

Comment: Is it possible that you are referencing to scattering with decreased wavelenght? if Yes i do not want the light to travel multiple km or even meters. https://www.cables-solutions.com/understanding-wavelengths-in-fiber-optics.html shows why they chose the specific wavelenghts. But it does not answer my question on what happens when the diameter is < wavelenght. I will search in parallel a bit more on the topic...

Comment: The photon gave the right answer. The water stream is nothing then a waveguide, just like an optical fibre. You cannot make the core arbitrarily small. Too small and the light leaks out of the waveguide quite fast. Search for a book on the principles of optical fibers. Single-mode fibers are usually dealt with soon after deriving the rules for step-index fibers.

Comment: Thank you very much, also thanks to Photon, but with this i would not understand why some features on semiconductors are as small as 4nm and 10nm apart from each other. In that theory this should not be possible. What i am missing here? @JoséAndrade

Comment: I don't know what semiconductor features you are referring to, but you specifically asked for the physics behind a passive waveguide and we provided you with the material to understand that. If you are talking about plasmonics, then those are completely different things from the water stream you asked about in here

Comment: @ThePhoton you can add your comment as a answer so i can chose it as the preferred solution and you get some points if you like. Plasmonics which Jose provided helped me to understand the limitation. But your comment was 100% accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you guide light along a stream of water, you're using the water as a *dielectric waveguide*. The light is guided by the boundary between a high-index core material (water) and the low-index cladding material around it (air).

In a dielectric waveguide, there is a minimum diameter for the core for any particular light wavelength, below which the guide does not support any propagating mode. This means there is no solution to the wave equation (or Maxwell's equations, if you prefer) with the boundary conditions introduced by the waveguide geometry, which propagates energy along the axis of the structure.

In the case of glass dielectric waveguides (optical fiber), the minimum core diameter is several times the optical wavelength (on the order of 5-10 um diameter for 850 - 1600 nm light, for example) because the index contrast is not especially strong.

For a waveguide with perfectly conducting boundaries, the waveguide could in principle be as small as about 1/2 the wavelength. An approximation to such a waveguide is commonly used for microwave wavelengths (but rectangular profiles are generally preferred to circular ones in order to control the signal polarization).

For a water-air waveguide, the minimum diameter is less, but there is an additional practical limitation because the shape of the waveguide can't be kept perfectly uniform due to the fluid nature of water (and air).

> if the waterstream gets ever smaller and smaller and smaller till it is smaller in size than the wavelenght of the laser diode itself, what would happen?

In the case where you apply a light beam to a waveguide too small to propagate it, you generate an *evanescent wave* into the waveguide. The bulk of the energy is reflected.

The evanescent wave is a field pattern that decays exponentially along the waveguide axis. No significant power can be transmitted along any significant distance by an evanescent wave. But power can be coupled over very short distances (generally less than a wavelength) by *evanescent coupling* (the mathematics of evanescent coupling are very similar to those for quantum tunneling).

Comment: (+1) Nice answer! And Plateau-Rayleigh instabilities complicate the situation a bit more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%E2%80%93Rayleigh_instability